# Creo Toolkit: how to fetch current Part, Assembly, Drawing

Tags: toolkit

Creo Toolkit: Need to know how to fetch current Part, Assembly, Drawing. Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
ProModeCurrentGet()
and 
ProMdlCurrentGet()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which toolkit you are using, if you are going with JAVA, the Toolkit API has multiple functions to fetch model(s).

- GetActiveModel()
- GetCurrentModel()
- RetrieveModel(ModelDescriptor MdlDescr) ... and more.